# Retirar espaços e acentos com PHP

Tags: php

Estou precisando retirar os espaços e acentos de uma palavra com a função abaixo, porém só os acentos são retirados. Como faço para retirar os espaços também?

```
$string="João é de Maranhão";
function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
}
echo tirarAcentos($string); // retorno Joao e de Maranhao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `str_replace` para tirar o espaço antes de tirar as acentuações:

```
$string="João é de Maranhão";
function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"), str_replace(" ", "", $string));
}
echo tirarAcentos($string); // retorno Joao e de Maranhao
```

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado Roberto de Campos.